# How to set default drop down list value from another drop down list in sheets?

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-apps-script

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a list that populates a drop down list created by data validation.  I then query the data to populate a second list based on the first drop down value. Everything works except I would like to set the first value in the second drop down to be the default value.  In other words if I change the value in the first drop down my second drop down now shows an error until I select the drop down and change the value to a correct value.  I would like to set it to the first correct value when the first drop down is changed.  My reason for this is I dont want someone to forget to change the second drop down and get a value that is not even in the range.

Please help I am new to this kind of thing.

thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U2_0Ku1bCLfDh_v2XyE9aQMSfdYmlVfX_8SKmQay48g/edit?usp=sharing

Here is what I have so far. It works except anytime the sheet is edited the value is reset. I only want it to reset when Cell A2 changes.

```
function onEdit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    // IF(cellContent has changed) then clear B2
    // else do nothing.
    sheet.getRange('B2').clearContent();
    var value = sheet.getRange('H2').getValue();
    sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this in apps script. If yes please post some code you have tried.

Comment: I am trying to complete this any way possible I am not sure how it can be done. Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out and this seems to work just fine.

```
  function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var cellR = cell.getRow();
  var cellC = cell.getColumn();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  var active_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var value = active_spreadsheet.getRange('H2').getValue();
  if (cellR == 2 && cellC == 1) {
    sheet.getRange('B2').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for coming across this problem and the solution.